# What "cscript //NoLogo" stands for?

Tags: java, file, jtextfield, filewriter, notepad

This is a java program code that runs the Notepad program and pastes a specific text stored in this program itself....

I was wondering if you can explain me the `String vbs` value, and also the `File file`, and the `("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath())` in the `Process p`.
If you are as generous, then please explain me the whole code.

I'm a beginner in Java, well not exactly but if u wanna judge from 0 to 10 i would be 1.5/10

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

 public class PasteToNotepad {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     String text = "Some text for testing.";
     JTextField textField = new JTextField(text);
     textField.setSelectionStart(0);
     textField.setSelectionEnd(text.length() - 1);
     textField.copy();

     String vbs = ""
             + "Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\")\n"
             + "WshShell.Run \"notepad\", 9\n"
             + "WScript.Sleep 500\n"
             + "WshShell.SendKeys \"^V\"";

     File file = File.createTempFile("PrintDialog", ".vbs");
     file.deleteOnExit();
     FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);
     fw.write(vbs);
     fw.close();
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
     p.waitFor();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Though this question *wasn't* primarily about `cscript //NoLogo`, regardless of its title, it still googles well for that phrase, so let's answer that in too much detail too.

I'm not sure why they call it a "logo", but it's exactly what you might think from the built-in help @MByD displayed. But in the interest of over-completeness...

```
C:\prompt>cscript spam.js
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\prompt>cscript //NoLogo spam.js

C:\prompt>
```

So if you're piping output and don't want all that Microsoft boilerplate, `//Nologo`-ify it.

```
C:\prompt>cscript spam.js > out.txt

C:\prompt>more out.txt
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\prompt>cscript spam.js //NoLogo > out.txt

C:\prompt>more out.txt

C:\prompt>
```

(`spam.js` has `var spam = "spam";` in it.)

And, wow, that is a horribly convoluted way to get text into Notepad. I'm guessing it's more about teaching how to write to a file and `exec` a command from Java, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

What you basically do is:

1. Create a String that contains a script (`String vbs = ...`)
2. Write it to a file (`File file = File...` to `fw.close()`)
3. Execute this script in a separate process by invoking cscript (`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`)

Regarding `cscript //NoLogo`, this has pretty much nothing to do with Java, this is a windows command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\bsharet>cscript
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: CScript scriptname.extension [option...] [arguments...]

Options:
 //B         Batch mode: Suppresses script errors and prompts from displaying
 //D         Enable Active Debugging
 //E:engine  Use engine for executing script
 //H:CScript Changes the default script host to CScript.exe
 //H:WScript Changes the default script host to WScript.exe (default)
 //I         Interactive mode (default, opposite of //B)
 //Job:xxxx  Execute a WSF job
 //Logo      Display logo (default)
 //Nologo    Prevent logo display: No banner will be shown at execution time
 //S         Save current command line options for this user
 //T:nn      Time out in seconds:  Maximum time a script is permitted to run
 //X         Execute script in debugger
 //U         Use Unicode for redirected I/O from the console
```

Comment: So how can this program run (Notepad.exe), and how could I change it?

Comment: The program runs **cscript**, not **notepad** then the script that is executed by **cscript** runs **notepad**. how to change it - it depends what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: lets say I want to run messenger which exists in "C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Messenger\msnmsgr.exe"

another thing, but how did this code ran the Notepad while there is not any path visible in this code?

Comment: that's because notepad.exe sits in the windows path, again, nothing java related, it's just windows.

Comment: Well so, one last thing you didn't answer me, where can I set the path if i wanna run something else not in Windows path? cause I tried to set the path instead of the notedpad word in this line: ( + "WshShell.Run \"notepad\", 9\n" ) without braces...

Comment: Yeah, I know about this step, but sorry I'm trying to run this program upon any device that has not this step set...